# how to get index as Int from Index? in Dictionary Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, indexof

I need to get index like 0,1,2,3... by key - `collectionName` which is String.
But I can only get "Index?"

What I'm doing wrong?
I have a Dictionary - collections

```swift
var collections: [String: (collectionName: String, isSynched: Bool)] = [:]

//some code

let index = collections.firstIndex{$0.key == collectionName}
//index: Dictionary<String, (collectionName: String, isSynched: Bool)>.Index?
```

But I need Int
like in simple array ["m", "s", "o"]

index of "m" is 0

index of "s" is 1

index of "o" is 2

Comment: collectionName it's a value for key, not in a tuple.

they just both have same names

Comment: show what your `collections` look like

Comment: po collections
▿ 7 elements
 ▿ 0 : 2 elements
 - key : "goals"
 ▿ value : 2 elements
  - collectionName : "Goals"
 - isSynched : false
▿ 1 : 2 elements
- key : "contacts"
▿ value : 2 elements
 - collectionName : "Contacts"
- isSynched : false
 ▿ 2 : 2 elements
 - key : "dialogs"
 ▿ value : 2 elements
 - collectionName : "Dialogues"
 - isSynched : true
 ▿ 3 : 2 elements
- key : "projects"
▿ value : 2 elements
- collectionName : "Projects"
- isSynched : false
▿ 4 : 2 elements
- key : "service_notes"
▿ value : 2 elements
- collectionName : "Service notes"
.....etc.

Comment: Since dictionaries are unordered it doesn't make much sense to get the index as an integer since you can't access it like `myDictionary[3]` anyway.

Comment: You could do `let value = collections.map {$0.key}.firstIndex(of: collectionName)` but I don't see the point of it.

Comment: Joakim Danielson, thank you very much! It solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Like said  Joakim Danielson I did

```
let value = collections.map {$0.key}.firstIndex(of: collectionName)
```

and then

```
let index = -(value.unsafelyUnwrapped.distance(to: 0))
```

and it solved the problem